# How many bytes does the Python string '\x80' in UTF8 occupy?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

How many bytes does '\x80' in UTF8 occupy?

In Python I write:

```
>>> '\x80'.encode('utf8')
b'\xc2\x80'
```

This indicates that '\x80' translates to *two* bytes.

Also, the other way around:

```
>>> b'\x80'.decode()
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Does this mean the *byte* '\x80' on its own has no (character) meaning in UTF-8?

Comment: Note: UTF-8 is an encoding, and independent of Python. A byte string is a list of bytes, so if you define just one byte, it will take one byte (+ overhead of python (e.g. type information, length). Strings in python has own representation (and it depends on python version), but you should probably ignore such implementation detail. `len` on a string gives the number of `unicode codepoints` (not the bytes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *unicode character* U+0080 (which is a control character: PAD) is encoded as two bytes in UTF-8, which are 0xC2 and 0x80.

The *byte stream* containing only the byte 0x80 does **not** represent a valid UTF-8  encoding of anything on its own (i.e. that byte alone is a misformed UTF-8 stream).

Basically each byte in a UTF-8 stream can be classified as one of three different types:

- single-byte sequences: bytes in the range 0x00-0x7F (0-127)  represent a single Unicode Codepoint on their own (this part is equivalent to the old US-ASCII encoding)
- leading bytes: bytes in the range 0xC0-0xFD (192-253) *start* a multi-byte sequence and indicate how long that sequence must be <sup>*</sup>
- continuation bytes: bytes in the range 0x80-0xBF (128-191) are the *rest* of a multi-byte sequence.

0x80 is a *continuation byte*, so it can't stand on its own (it has to be preceded with a leading byte and possibly some other continuation bytes to be valid).

The [Wikipedia article on UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) has some very extensive documentation with good examples.

<sup>* Note that some leading bytes can never appear in valid UTF-8 for various reasons, so the range of actually *used* leading bytes is smaller. Similarly 0xFE and 0xFF are just never used so can also never appear in valid UTF-8.</sup>